# How to call an array from a data file in a blade template with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm learning Laravel and I need your help to display an array in a blade template.
First,I created a data file containing an array in App (I don't use a database in my project yet => everything is in a file).But in my template, I can't include this file and then loop over it.
I tried with @includes, required and use but nothing works .Besides, I don't quite understand the difference between the three if someone can explain it to me.. However, my dd works very well.
Can I have your help pleaz?
Thank you very much

App/Data.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Data{

    public static function getSkills()
    {
        return [
            // array data
            array("name" => "HTML5"),
            array("name" => "CSS3"),
            array("name" => "Sass"),
            array("name" => "Bootstrap"),
            array("name" => "JavaScript"),
            array("name" => "MySQL"),
            array("name" => "PHP"),
            array("name" => "React JS"),
            array("name" => "Redux"),
            array("name" => "GitHub"),
            array("name" => "Trello"),
            array("name" => "VSCode"),
            array("name" => "Linux Ubuntu"),
        ];
    }
}
```

SkillsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Data;

class SkillsController extends Controller
{

    public function allSkills()
    {
        return view('skills', [
            'skills' => Data::getSkills()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Skills.blade.php

```
@include('layouts/navbar')

<div id="competences">
    <div className="skills">
      <h1 className="skills-title"><span>*</span>Skills</h1>
      <h2 className="subtitle"><span>•</span> Languages and frameworks</h2>
      <ul className="skills-list">
      @foreach ($skills as $skill)
    <p>This is user {{ $skill->name }}</p>
        @endforeach

          <li className="skills-list-skill" key={skill.icon}>
            <img src={skill.icon} alt="" className="skills-list-skill-icon" />
            <p className="skills-list-skill-title">{skill.title}</p>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="secondary-skills"
    </div>
  </div>
@include ('layouts/footer')
```

[image: files]

Comment: Don't access that class statically from the view. It's better to call the method `getSkills()` in the controller and just pass the response (the array) to the view from the controller. If you remove hard dependencies (like calling the calls directly from the view), you're able to reuse views better. Views should only care about presentation and shouldn't need to know where the data is located.

Comment: I just edited my first post but I'm sure I forgot something because it still doesn't work

Comment: What does not work, surely there must be errors then right?

Comment: Yes! Undefined Variable $skills (foreach loop inside the blade template)

Comment: If the posted code is the code that are used (using that `allSkills()`-controller and the `skills`-view), that error makes no sense. Are you 100% sure that this is the controller used? If you enter `die('foobar');` in the top of the `allSkills()`-method, what happens?

Comment: I get "ErrorException
Undefined variable: skills (View: /home/student/Bureau/Portfolio/resources/views/competences.blade.php)"

Comment: I've also tried this one found on StackOverflow : Route::get('/competences', 'SkillsController@allSkills');

Comment: With this method : Route::get('/competences', 'SkillsController@allSkills'); I get "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [SkillsController] does not exist." I don't understand why :(

Comment: Yes I forgot to do the translation here sorry:) my site is in French that's why:) But there was no error on that side. competences= skills in French. But everything is "competences" in my project. I just adapted it here so you understand the meaning. Sorry :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found an issue!
My routing was :

```
Route::get('/competences',SkillsController@allSkills);
```

Actually the good method is :

```
Route::get('/competences',[SkillsController::class, 'allSkills']);
```

Nothing was working until I found this on Laracast's forums

Comment: I said I have no idea ... I suspected that the problem came from my route because  I do not know laravel. I haven't changed anything else. Be indulgent with people who are beginners thank you.We're here to help each other.